# Minecraft Server Message

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I just made a vanilla Minecraft 1.10.2 server and I want the server to send a personalized message every 30 minutes and if possible also clear all dropped items. 
Thank you.

Comment: I dont really know what to try

Comment: Well, in general, you'll get better a better response if you show some effort on your part rather than simply asking for someone to do it for you, from what I've seen.

Comment: I tried doing the help command but they didn't give me any info

Comment: You haven't said what kind of server. Vanilla or bukkit.

Comment: vanilla using the minecraft website

Comment: also its 1.10.2

Answer (score 1):

First, make an objective:

`/scoreboard objectives add time dummy`

Then, on an always active repeat command block, have the following command:

`/scoreboard players add Timer time 1`

On a chain command block coming out of it:

`/scoreboard players test Timer time 36000`

The 36000 is the result of 20 (ticks) * 60 (seconds) * 30 (minutes)

Next, have a conditional chain command block running out of that command block:

`/tellraw @a {"text":"whatever you want"}`

And another conditional chain for the item clear:

`/kill @e[type=Item]`

Lastly, the time score must be reset with a conditional chain command block:

`/scoreboard players reset Timer time`

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a script that does exactly this as one of its functions.

https://github.com/Veritas83/Minecraft.SNAPSHOT.Commands.Mod

Here is the relevant code I used to do what you're asking. You can disable all functions of the script and just use this function in the config :)

In config, make sure `useautoclear` is True

For 30min timer set, `autoclearint` to 1800.

Adjust the rest of the config to your needs. Setting your own MOTD and command line to start your server.

```
##
#Timed Functions
##
if useautosave == True and ((currtime - lasttimesave) > autosaveint):
    lasttimesave = time.time()
    autosave = "save-all\n"
    print "[" + get24hrtime() + "] [Script thread/EXEC]: " + autosave,
    p.stdin.write(autosave)
    autosave = 'tellraw @a {"text":"World saved. Autosave by ' + ver + '","color":"yellow"}\n'
    print "[" + get24hrtime() + "] [Script thread/EXEC]: " + autosave,
    p.stdin.write(autosave)
if useautoclear == True and ((currtime - lasttimeclear) > (autoclearint-60)):
    if clearwarn60 == False:
        if ((currtime - lasttimeclear) > (autoclearint-60)):
            autoclear = 'tellraw @a {"text":"Clearing Items in 1 minute!","color":"aqua"}\n'
            clearwarn60 = True
            print "[" + get24hrtime() + "] [Script thread/EXEC]: " + autoclear,
            p.stdin.write(autoclear)
    if clearwarn10 == False:
        if ((currtime - lasttimeclear) > (autoclearint-10)):
            autoclear = 'tellraw @a {"text":"Clearing items in 10 seconds!","color":"aqua"}\n'
            clearwarn10 = True
            print "[" + get24hrtime() + "] [Script thread/EXEC]: " + autoclear,
            p.stdin.write(autoclear)
if useautoclear == True and ((currtime - lasttimeclear) > autoclearint):
    lasttimeclear = time.time()
    autoclear = "kill @e[type=Item]\n"
    print "[" + get24hrtime() + "] [Script thread/EXEC]: " + autoclear,
    p.stdin.write(autoclear)
    autoclear = 'tellraw @a {"text":"Items cleared. Autoclear by ' + ver +  '","color":"aqua"}\nlist\n'
    p.stdin.write(autoclear)
    clearwarn60 = False
    clearwarn10 = False
```